# Chrome extension. New and don't know what i did wrong

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, url

This is my first project and I'm trying to make a simple chrome extension that on clicked edits a section of the current URL. but whenever I click it nothing runs.
how do I make it actually interact with and change the tab URL? 
here is what I have

Manifest.json

```
{
"name": "HalfScreen",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"description": "Larger window screen for youtube",
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
        },

"permissions": [
    "tabs"
],

"content_scripts": [
{
"matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/watch*", "http://www.youtube.com/watch*"],
    "js": ["inject.js"]
    }
],

"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]

}
```

Background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true, 
    currentWindow: true}, 
    function(tabs)
{
var tab = tabs[0];
var myUrl = tab.url;

chrome.tabs.executeScript (null, { file: inject.js });
    var URL = request.url;
});
```

inject.js

```
var pageInfo = {
"url": window.location.href
};
window.location = url.replace('watch?v=', 'v/');
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(pageInfo);
```

I'm open to any suggestions. I'm new to this and need some tips. thanks a lot.

Comment: I think you are talking about this http://stackoverflow.com/a/42143480/6738841

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I took your code and played around with it until I got it to work. This is the results. Works for me.

> .HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>YouTube Large Viewer</title>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
         <button id = "button" type="button">click me</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

> .JS:

```
window.addEventListener("load", loadFunctions);

function loadFunctions() {
    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
         chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'windowId': chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT},
         function(tabs){
            chrome.tabs.create({url: tabs[0].url.replace('watch?v=', 'v/')
         });
      });
   });
}
```

> manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "HalfScreen",
  "description": "Larger window screen for YouTube.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "images/favicon.png",
   "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
  "icons": { 
    "60": "images/icon.png" 
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Comment: So what was the problem?

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I've learned a lot just by reading your code. Looking forward to playing with it even more now that you got it working. Cheers

Comment: @CarlosARodriguez Glad to help. If you have any other questions, ask away!

Comment: TIP: If the only purpose of this extension is what you described, then you may want to remove the button and just call the function upon clicking on the extension icon. No need to open a page just to be able to click a button. The icon can act as the button.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Why have you changed the code from the OP to instead of using just a browser action button, to using a popup just to present the user with yet another single button (so the user now has to click *twice* to perform the only possible function)? That is bad UI design, and unnecessarily complicating the solution for the OP.